# Bulk convert xls to csv using LibreOffice

Tags: conversion, libreoffice

The following works fine:

`"path_to_libreoffice\soffice.exe" --convert-to csv test.xls`

However, when I try to convert all xls files in the folder nothing happens:

`"path_to_libreoffice\soffice.exe" --convert-to csv *.xls`

I can copy all xls filenames and do it like that, but why wouldn't `*.xls` work?

Comment: Because it doesn't understand wildcards?

Comment: But all the examples I've found online claim it does. Or did they mean "filename" by the asterisk...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux version will have wild-cards expanded by the shell into a list of matching files.

The Windows version should accept a file list, but `cmd` will not expand this for you.

The easiest answer is to use a `for` statement:

```
for %f in (*.xls) do "path_to_libreoffice\soffice.exe" --convert-to csv "%f"
```

Note that `%f` will need to be replaced by `%%f` in a batch file.

This is less efficient that supplying a file list, where all the conversions are done in a single schedule, whereas this performs a separate schedule for each conversion.

It might be possible to create a single schedule and file list from wild-cards, but this would require complex scripting. Alternatively, you could use a Windows port of `bash`.

Comment: Thanks for this but I've hit problems with not all files converted. I think this may be because Windows is running the commands too quickly without waiting for the conversion to finish.